# How to download big CSV files(about 250MB) while running on IIS10? Content-length=0

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I have .net5.0 REST API hosted on IIS 10. I want to have a method to export data via CSV file.

Code example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("download-file")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    var data = GetData();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream: ms, encoding: new UTF8Encoding(true)))
        {
            using (var cw = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true))
            {
                cw.WriteRecords(data);
            }
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "fileName.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

It works when there is not much data.

The problem appears when file size raises up to 250MB then I get content-length: 0 without any errors. It happens only when the API hosted on IIS, when I host the API in Kestrel everything fine.

I guess IIS has some response content length limitation.
I tried setting maxAllowedContentLength attribute in web.config/directly in IIS in requestFiltering, but no results.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#server-and-app-configuration

Comment: *Don't* use either a MemoryStream or a `byte[]` array. Right now the code creates *two* copies of the data in memory before it even starts sending the data to the browser. BTW a CSV file is a text file, not binary. The correct content type is `text/csv`

Answer (score 0):

IIS has a download/upload limit of 28.6MB. You will need to increase the your limit. You can do that by Editing the Web.config file in the folder (not necessary the visual studio project).

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="{Your Number Here: Example 2147483648}" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```